# Xcode setting label's text from variable passed from another viewController causes crash

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

This is the code that presents the next VC:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("dismiss completed")
    let user = self.users[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toNewMessage", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

    var vc = segue.destination as! ChatLogController
    vc.user = self.users[(indexPath?.row)!]
}
```

And that is the variable that gets the data from the previous VC:

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        print(user?.name)
        chatLogTitleLabel.text = user?.name
    }
}
```

It says it found a nil value when I try to set the label's text, but when I print it it's the correct value, not nil. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `didSet` and set this inside `viewDidLoad`

```
chatLogTitleLabel.text = user?.name
```

The problem is this

```
vc.user = self.users[(indexPath?.row)!]
```

triggers setting the label which is nil at that  moment as all outlets are nil until the vc is loaded/presented

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I thought it executes before the varible has been set.

Answer (score 0):

Outlets aren't connected in the moment when code inside `prepare(for:sender:)` is called. You need to set `text` of your label after they are, so for example in `viewDidLoad`

```
var user: User?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    chatLogTitleLabel.text = user?.name
}
```

---

Anyway, when you're performing segue, you can pass selected `User` as `sender` and then in `prepare(for:sender:)` downcast it

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toNewMessage", sender: users[indexPath.row])
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toNewMessage" {
        var vc = segue.destination as! ChatLogController
        vc.user = sender as! User
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        print(user?.name)
        chatLogTitleLabel.text = user?.name
    }
}
```

You are setting the value of `chatLogTitleLabel.text` before its initialisation.
you have to do this after the loading the view. in `viewDidLoad` / `viewWillApper` or `viewDidAppear`. or load the view of next controller before assigning value to `user`.

Answer (score 0):

As other have said, this happens because the view, and all outlets, haven't been loaded yet. You can fix this by setting the label text in viewDidLoad instead, or you can load the view, if not already loaded, in your didSet, like this:

```
var user: User? {
    didSet {
        loadViewIfNeeded()
        chatLogTitleLabel.text = user?.name
    }
}
```